# How to remove duplicate entries within a column in a database with a large number of columns

Tags: excel, database, duplicates

I need to create an excel database for a simulation with about 1000 users. Each user has a shopping list with between 0-100 items.

I have separately created a random list of shopping items with 300 items in total.

What I would like to know is how do I randomly assign shopping items to each user without repeating the item twice in each users shoppig bag (users can only have carrots for example appear once in their shopping bag) and given that each user might have different number of items in their shopping bag? Thank you for your help, Sue

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly like shuffling and dealing playing cards *(with 300 items rather than 52 cards)*:

```
For each player
   randomize the items
   pick a random number of samples
   assign that user those samples
repeat for the next user
```

Using this approach, a given user cannot have any item repeated *(just like a user cannot be dealt 2 3-of-hearts)*.  Therefore, removing duplicates is not an issue.

This can easily be simulated in Excel.